# R regex to parse token after @ also with no additional tokens in string

Tags: regex, r, gsub

I have a problem in parsing address in text strings. The usual address will be "@address token token token" or "@address token token /ntoken".

```
string <- c("@address token token token", "@address token token /ntoken")
gsub("^\\.?@([a-z0-9_]{1,25})[^a-z0-9_]+.*$", "\\1", string)
```

which are correctly parsed

```
[1] "address" "address"
```

yet, in some circumstances the address will be the only token in the string, then regex will return the address including the @

```
string <- c("@address token token token", "@address token token /ntoken", "@address")
gsub("^\\.?@([a-z0-9_]{1,25})[^a-z0-9_]+.*$", "\\1", string)
# [1] "address"  "address"  "@address"
```

How to instruct regex to manage also the one-token only case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> in some circumstances the address will be the only token in the string, then regex will return the address including the @

because in that case there is no match.

Just make a slight change:

convert `[^a-z0-9_]+` into `[^a-z0-9_]?` to make it **optional**.

```
^\.?@([a-z0-9_]{1,25})[^a-z0-9_]?.*$
```

Here is [Online demo](http://regex101.com/r/sY4hQ0/1)

Answer (score 1):

Use word boundary:

```
gsub("^\\.?@([a-z0-9_]{1,25})\\b.*$", "\\1", string)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `strapplyc` from the [gsubfn package](http://gsubfn.googlecode.com) the regex can be simplified substantially.  This returns the portion of the regex that matches the part of the regex within parentheses:

```
library(gsubfn)
string <- c("@address token token token", "@address token token /ntoken", 
   "@address")

strapplyc(string, "@([a-z0-9_]{1,25})", simplify = TRUE)
## [1] "address" "address" "address"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
library(stringr)
 str_extract(string, perl('(?<=@)[a-z0-9_]{1,25}'))
#[1] "address" "address" "address"
```